# Get Checkbox value in MVC Controller parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a checkbox in my view that I am posting back to the Controller as a parameter, but when the checkbox is checked the controller receives the value as a string "on", and when unchecked the value in the parameter is "off". Is there any way to have this value postback as an int or bool? When I try bool below it is always null because it doesn't match the data type.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option">food</label>


        public ActionResult Select(bool? option)
        {....
```

Comment: Try adding `id="option"` to your input element

Comment: Thanks but that did not work. The only way could get this work was by using the Html checkbox Helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to use the Html checkbox helper for this to work, which seems silly to me because it renders and works correctly client side when you create html without using the helper.

```
<label>@Html.CheckBox("option", false) food</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add `value` attribute to your `checkbox` and set it to `true` or `false`.

MVT will not recognize `option` as true here

`<input type="checkbox" name="option" checked="checked" />`

but will if you add `value="true"`

`<input type="checkbox" name="option" checked="checked" value="true" />`

Script that does it:

```
$(document).on("click", "[type='checkbox']", function(e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).attr("value", "true");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("value","false");}
    });
```